# Why is 0 not a limit point of this metric space in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

The open set $\left\lbrace \left(1/n, n \right) : n \in \mathbb{N} \right\rbrace$ under the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb {R}^2$.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote down the right set? $\{(1/n,n): n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not open.

Comment: Is "0" an element of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$? The elements of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ are ordered pairs of the form $(x,y)$ where $x\in\Bbb R$, $y\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, but how is it not open....I mean (1/2 , 2) or (1/3 , 3) are open sets.

Comment: Why do you think it is?

Comment: I think the OP is confused about the meaning of $(\frac12,2)$ and similar "notations". On one hand, the question talks twice about $\mathbb R^2$, so it makes sense to interpret $(\frac12,2)$ as a point in the 2-dim. Euclidean plane, with $x$-coordinate $\frac12$ and $y$-coordinate 2. OTOH, they comment that  $(\frac12,2)$ is open, which sounds like they think it is an open interval of real numbers.

Comment: Yes I have been considering it as an open interval...a subspace of $\mathbb {R^2}$ How is it to be interpreted if not that?

Comment: I think that's wrong. The first interpretation I gave seems the one that is most appropriate for the question.
Your interpretation doesn't make much sense, the open interval $(\frac12,2)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^1$, not $\mathbb R^2$. While you can of course embed such an interval into $\mathbb R^2$, it wouldn't be open in $\mathbb R^2$, because for that an entire (if small) 2-dimensional disk around any point of it would have to be part of the interval. But that's not what happens, no matter how you embed.

Comment: Given real numbers $a,b$, the notation $(a,b)$ has two meanings, and you are perhaps confusing them. The first meaning of $(a,b)$ is an open interval on the number line, namely the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $a < x < b$. The second meaning of $(a,b)$ is a point in the coordinate plane, namely the point whose $x$-coordinate equals $a$ and whose $y$-coordinate equals $b$. The set in your question is a subset of the coordinate plane that is defined using the second meaning, **not** the first.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In red the some points of the your set.

Answer (score 0):

I guess  the op is talking the set $\{(1/n,n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. This set has no limit points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric

Comment: Yes, can you show how it doesn't have a limit point because from my understanding at least 0 should be a limit point

Comment: Any two points in the set are at least of distance $>1$ (This is due to Pythagorean Theorem)